# Semi-Circle arc Scroll javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve something like this http://www.ibeyi.fr but I don't know where to start. Any steps in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Zaire, is it the goal for this to work on tablets and smartphones? As there is no "hover" on those devices, you will spend time making something that only works on laptops and desktops. Apart from that, you can change the image with jQuery attr(). Your example has four images.

Comment: It's true that any effect like this will probably only work on desktops.  The authors of the Skrollr library itself says "To be honest, mobile support always sucked (because mobile browsers are hard) and you shouldn't compromise UX for some fancy UI effects. Ever."

Answer (score 0):

They are using a library called [skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/).  That on its own won't give you semicircle effect.

Basically they are rotating the entire semi-circle element as the page scrolls, and then rotating the contained elements in the opposite direction to offset the rotation.

To see this in action, inspect one of the spinning elements and watch `transform` property change as you scroll.

Comment: Great, I'm going to let that sink in and read about skrollr. Thank you, I was very much lost